# Percentage load balance thread requests

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing

I have a pool of worker threads in which I send request to them based on percentage. For example, worker 1 must process 60% of total requests, worker 2 must process 31% of total requests and lastly worker 3 processes 9%. I need to know mathematically how to scale down the numbers and maintain ratio so I don't have to send 60 requests to thread 1 and then start sending requests to worker 2. It sounds like a "Linear Scale" math approach. In any case, all inputs on this issue  are appreciated

Comment: "I need to know mathematically how to scale down the numbers and maintain ratio so I don't have to send 60 requests to thread 1 and then start sending requests to worker 2." -- This is confusing, because now you seem to be talking about the *order* in which you send requests to threads.  But that is independent of the *total number* of requests to send (which is what you appear to be asking for at the start, and which is easy to calculate -- if a worker needs 60% of the jobs, just send `nTotalJobs * 0.6` to it).

Comment: number of workers is dynamic as well as the percentages. nTotalJobs cannot be computed because requests takes place in real time and no queue involved to count pending jobs.

Comment: I see.  Writing up an idea now.  BTW it pays to put details like that in the main question -- obvious to you but not to readers necessarily!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about this problem makes it quite similar to the problem of drawing a sloped line on a pixel-based display, which can be done with [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

First let's assume for simplicity that there are only 2 workers, and that they should take a fraction p (for worker 1) and (1-p) (for worker 2) of the incoming requests.  Imagine that "Requests sent to worker 1" is the horizontal axis and "Requests sent to worker 2" is the vertical axis of a graph: what we want to do is draw a (pixelated) line in this graph that starts at (0, 0) and has slope (1-p)/p (i.e. it advances (1-p) units upwards for every p units it advances rightwards).  When a new request comes in, a new pixel gets drawn.  This new pixel will always be either immediately to the right of the previous pixel (if we assign the job to worker 1) or immediately above it (if we assign it to worker 2), so it's not quite like Bresenham's algorithm where diagonal movements are possible, but there are similarities.

With each new request that comes in, we have to assign that request to one of the workers, corresponding to drawing the next pixel rightwards or upwards from the previous one.  I propose that a good way to pick the right direction is to pick the one that **minimises an error function.**  The easiest thing to do is to take the slope of the line between (0, 0) and the point that would result from each of the 2 possible choices, and compare these slopes to the ideal slope (1-p)/p; then pick whichever one produces the lowest difference.  This will cause the drawn pixels to "track" the ideal line as closely as possible.

To generalise this to more than 2 dimensions (workers), we can't use slope directly.  If there are W workers, we need to come up with some function error(X, Y), where X and Y are both W-dimensional vectors, one representing the ideal *direction* (the ratios of requests to assign, analogous to the slope (1-p)/p earlier), the other representing the candidate point, and returning some number representing how different their directions are.  Fortunately this is easy: we can take the **cosine of the angle between two vectors** by dividing their [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) by the product of their magnitudes, which is easy to calculate.  This will be 1 if their directions are identical, and less than 1 otherwise, so when a new request arrives, all we need to do is perform this calculation for each of worker 1 <= i <= W and see which one's error(X, Y[i]) is closest to 1: that's the worker to give the request to.

**[EDIT]**

This procedure will also adapt to changes in the ideal direction.  But as it stands, it tries (as hard as it can) to make the *overall ratios of every request assigned so far* track the ideal direction, so if the procedure has been running a long time, then even a small adjustment in the target direction could result in large "swings" to compensate.  In that case, when calling error(X, Y[i]), it might be better to compute the second argument using the difference between the latest pixel (request assignment) and the pixel from some number k (e.g. k=100) steps ago.  (In the original algorithm, we are implicitly subtracting the starting point (0, 0), i.e. k is as large as possible.)  This only requires you to keep the last k chosen endpoints.  Picking k too large will mean you can still get large swings, while picking k too small might mean that the "line" drifts well off-course, with some workers never picked at all, because each assignment alters the direction so drastically.  You might need to experiment to find a good k.

Comment: I do appreciate the insights. That's a lot for me to experiment with. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome!  If it's helpful, please consider upvoting (hint, hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

To keep the assignments non-clustered, associate merits with each workers jobs inversely proportional to the intended share, e.g., 31 * 9 for w1, 60 * 9 for w2, and 31 * 60 for w3. Start mit no merits for each worker, next job goes to worker with least merits, and lesser ordinal in case of ties. Accumulate merits for jobs done. (On overflow from one accumulator, subtract MAXVALUE - 31 * 60 from each.)